# drop in Java framework/library providing registration wizard, email confirmation, password complexity

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, frameworks, registration

I have an existing Java servlet app as a war file developed by another team, which has very limited user registration capabilities and validations.

We have a security policy to require password complexity and email confirmation so I would like to add the required features to this existing app, but without making any code changes to their source code/war.

So I would like to add this functionality to the app by redirecting their registration page to my new registration page, (which I will do with apache mod_redirect)

Is there a very lightweight, Java library that provides registration wizard functionality that I can "drop in" to write its results to a MysQL database backend.

Ideally I just want to specify a list of required fields, and their database table/column mapping, and specify and SMTP server, and some templates etc and have it live next to my existing war deployment.

something like this;

http://www.mydomain.com/app1/register

"/register" redirects using apache to

http://www.mydomain.com/app2/register

and have some simple java app to handle the user registration, validation and email confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Emmet](http://metadata.net/sites/emmet-0.4/).  It supports most if not all of the things that you asked for:

- password quality checking,
- self-registration with email confirmation,
- SQL backend
- templates for emails

Also

- RESTful web apis,
- tailorable permissions and access control (for Emmet and your application),
- administration pages and user account management pages implemented as JSPs,
- user profiles,
- various authentication schemes (user/password, OpenId, Shibboleth, hybrids)

Emmet is designed to be used as a stand-alone webapp, or to be integrated with another webapp using Maven WAR file overlays.  It uses various Spring technologies, including SpringSecurity.

(Disclaimer - I'm the lead developer.)

Comment: Hi, the link to the demo installation is broken on this page;http://metadata.net/sites/emmet-0.4/installation.html